# How to hide some output of WMIC query

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I've a batch that kill certain processes. After starting it, I want to hide *`Ignoring: <ProcessName>`* and display only *`Terminating: <ProcessName>`*, so how I can do this ?

```
@echo off
cls
title prockiller
setlocal

:Whitelist
set "whitelist=Microsoft Avast Panda ESET Kaspersky Avira AVG Bitdefender Malwarebytes Norton McAfee GAS IBM"

:Analyze
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process get executablepath^,status /format:csv ^| find "\"'
) do (
    set "proc=%%~I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    wmic datafile where "name='!proc:\=\\!'" get manufacturer 2>nul | findstr /i "%whitelist%" >nul && (
        echo Ignoring: %%~nI
    ) || (
        echo Terminating: %%~nI && taskkill /im "%%~nxI" /f /t >nul 2>&1
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO you edited your question to death. How can someone understand your current code fragments with remaining for variables without knowing their origin. Please [edit] one last time with a [mcve] after having thought about it.

Comment: Sorry but I tried to be more summarized, anyway edited with the whole code.

Comment: Change `echo Ignoring: %%~nI` to `REM echo Ignoring: %%~nI` -- or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You do know that when you get the `2`nd token from the `csv` containing `executablepath,status` that you're completely wasting time retrieving `status` since you can't use it? Also the command will output the `status` as `%%I` not `executablepath` which is what it looks like you were hoping for.

Comment: @compo for me it worked ! i'm on french machine windows 7

Comment: My mistake, the `/format:csv` option does make it work, but more by fortune than I'm willing to accept. `wmic process get executablepath,status /format:csv` should return, including header, `Node,ExecutablePath,Status` so the second token would be okay in that scenario. However it is a known issue that `/format:csv` doesn't work on many systems because the required `csv.xsl` file does not exist in the default correct location, as with mine. Also, I believe that `Status` is always returned empty so not required and empty `Manufacturer` entries may be returned due to having no data contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick untested version:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Process killer with a whitelist

Set "IPL=Avast AVG Avira BitDefender ESET GAS IBM Kaspersky Malwarebytes"
Set "IPL=%IPL% McAfee Microsoft Norton Panda"

For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'WMIC Process Where "Not ExecutablePath Is Null" Get ExecutablePath'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%~A") Do Call :Sub %%~B
Timeout -1
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "proc=%*"
For %%A In ("%proc:\=\\%") Do (
    WMIC DataFile Where "Name='%%~A' And Not Manufacturer Is Null"^
     Get Manufacturer|FindStr/IVX "Manufacturer"|FindStr/I "%IPL%">Nul||(
        Echo Terminating "%proc%"
        Echo=TaskKill /F /IM "%%~nxA" /T))
```

Remove `Echo=` from the last line, *and optionally the `Timeout -1` line*, if the console output looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of igonring process list into a file for logging if you want like this :

```bat
@echo off
Title Process killer with a white list
cls
setlocal
set "Ignoring_Process_List=%~dpn0_Ignoring_Process_List.txt"
set "Terimnated_Process_List=%~dpn0_Terimnated_List.txt"
If exist "%Ignoring_Process_List%" Del "%Ignoring_Process_List%"
If exist "%Terimnated_Process_List%" Del "%Terimnated_Process_List%"

:Whitelist
set "whitelist=Microsoft Avast Panda ESET Kaspersky Avira AVG Bitdefender Malwarebytes Norton McAfee GAS IBM"

:Analyze
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process get executablepath^,status /format:csv ^| find "\"'
) do (
    set "proc=%%~I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    wmic datafile where "name='!proc:\=\\!'" get manufacturer 2>nul | findstr /i "%whitelist%" >nul && (
        ( echo Ignoring: %%~nxI )>>!Ignoring_Process_List! 2>&1
    ) || (
        ( echo Terminating: %%~nxI )>con
        ( echo Terminating: %%~nxI && Taskkill /im "%%~nxI" /f /t )>>!Terimnated_Process_List! 2>&1
    )
    endlocal 
)
Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul
```

Comment: @Compo Ok and how final code would be? Just replace this line?

Comment: @wagner4362  this code worked for me ! and did you tried it or not ?

Comment: @Hackoo Yes worked but I believe there is a way to do more fast this task